# Create different instances in a loop

Tags: java, loops, object

how can I create an instance for each object in a loop and have each instance handle the specific object and not be an instance for all objects in the loop?

What I am trying to do is to differentiate the progress, if it is completed from the challenge if there are two of the same type.

In this case I have two challenges of the same type but it is only taking me one or when I complete one it completes both. Maybe I'm doing everything wrong and it's not the way, first time I'm getting into this kind of things, thanks.

My loop class:

```
for (Challenge challenge : challengeList) {

    if (plugin.getChallengeManager().canCompleteChallenge(playerUUID, challenge)
            || !plugin.getChallengeManager().isSameChallengeType(challenge, ChallengeType.COLLECT)) continue;

    Map<UUID, ChallengeHolder> challengeHolderMap = new HashMap<>(); //I am trying to create a Hashmap for each Challenge 

    challengeHolderMap.put(playerUUID, new ChallengeHolder(challenge, 1, false));
    Challenge challengeHolderChallenge = challengeHolderMap.get(playerUUID).getChallenge();
    int playerProgress = challengeHolderMap.get(playerUUID).getProgress();
    boolean isCompleted =  challengeHolderMap.get(playerUUID).isCompleted();
    int challengeCondition = challenge.getChallengeCondition();

    if (isCompleted) continue;

    ItemStack itemStack = new ItemStack(new ChallengeReplacer(plugin).replaceItemStack(challengeHolderChallenge));
    if (!generatorItem.isSimilar(itemStack)) continue;

    if (playerProgress < challengeCondition) continue;

    int challengeRemaining = plugin.getDatabaseManager().getChallengeRemaining(playerUUID, challengeHolderChallenge);

    if (playerProgress >= challengeCondition) {
        plugin.getChallengeManager().updateChallenge(playerUUID, challengeHolderChallenge, (challengeRemaining - 1));
        challengeHolderMap.get(playerUUID).setCompleted(true);
        challengeHolderMap.get(playerUUID).setProgress(playerProgress);
      
    }
}
```

My holder class for challenge:

```
public class ChallengeHolder {

private Challenge challenge;
private int progress;
private boolean completed;

    public ChallengeHolder(Challenge challenge, int progress, boolean completed) {
        this.challenge = challenge;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    /**
     * @return The challenge.
     */
    public Challenge getChallenge() {
        return this.challenge;
    }

    /**
     * Set the challenge.
     *
     * @param challenge The challenge.
     */
    public void setChallenge(Challenge challenge) {
        this.challenge = challenge;
    }

    /**
     * @return The progress of the challenge in the current game.
     */
    public int getProgress() {
        return this.progress;
    }

    /**
     * Set the progress for the challenge.
     *
     * @param progress Progress to be set for the challenge.
     */
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the challenge is completed in the current game.
     */

public boolean isCompleted() {
        return this.completed;
    }

/**
 * Change the status for the challenge.
 *
 * @param completed The status to be set for the challenge.
 */
public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with methodology. How, or from where is this loop being run? You have a mix of player specific actions mixed in with what should be a global challenge tracker. Rather than creating a new `ChallengeHolder` for every single challenge for every single player, you should instead create a single `ChallengeHolder` per player that tracks all challenges for that player. The next question is, how do you reference the `challengeHolderMap` if you create it within your loop? This variable needs to be moved outside the loop, and it should be independent of any player events.

Comment: I was doing fine, my problem was that I was storing the UUID of the player instead of the Challenge

I have managed to make them distinguishable, still, is there a better way to do it?

As you mention I have moved challengeHolderMap out of the loop and it works perfect, thank you very much! The loop is running every time a player picks up an object from the ground

Comment: I am not sure what is in your `challengeList` array, but checking every challenge and creating new variables every time a player picks up a block means a lot more processing needs to happen, so the server/game may run slower because of it (Example: If this is a server plugin, and you have 100 players picking up blocks at the same time it may quickly slow down your server). I suspect for your small use case it will not be an issue, but you want to think about how you can prevent creating new objects every time the action happens.